# API-calls without Appserver

Tags: rest, openedge, progress-4gl

I have googled and tried some solutions but so far, nothing works. 
I am trying to do some API-calls (REST) from a 4gl / OpenEdge procedure. However, there is no AppServer available and I have no clue if that is necessary to do an API-call. I am not a OpenEdge expert and none of my colleagues have a clue :X 
Is there anyone that knows if this is possible, and if so, an example for doing this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an HTTP client to perform the call.

RTFM ;)

https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/dvpin%2Fmaking-http(s)-requests-from-abl-applications.html%23wwconnect_header

Some examples there:

https://github.com/PeterJudge-PSC/http_samples
I used this to implement my calls (GET, POST, etc.) with 11.5 & 11.6. Works great.

Comment: Pfff, I feel a little stupid now, I did find this OpenEdge.Net.pl thing online but it wasn't in the dir it was supposed to be in. I thought.. Turns out I checked the wrong dir. I'm gonna crawl in a corner now ok bye ;)